# how to display record data depending on user login (java- sqlserver)

Tags: java, sql-server, database

how to display record data depending on user login? 
Means when a logged in to application page, data or record searched must be related to user. 
thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way might be to use the SQL-Server [SUSER_NAME()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187934.aspx) function.  For example:

```
select <<some data>> from <<some table>> where SUSER_NAME() = "selected_user"
```